# input range slider thumb js event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

In input range slider I want to increase operable area size will increase when mouse over in thumb.
I have tried this

HTML

```
<input id="param1" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" class="slider-color">
```

Jquery

```
$('.slider-color::-webkit-slider-thumb').hover(function(){
    $('.slider-color::-webkit-slider-runnable-track').css('height','11px');
});
```

Please help. Above is not working

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can catch the hover on the `slider-thumb` but here is an idea in case you want the hover on all the slider where you can rely on CSS variable to change some properties

```css
.slider-color:hover {
  --c:red;
  --h:40px;
}
.slider-color::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background:var(--c,transparent);
  height:var(--h,initial);
}
```

```html
<input id="param1" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" class="slider-color">
```

Comment: When I hover on slider its changing height. I want it hover on thumb not in slider bar

Comment: @RejoanulAlam Yes as I said, I don't think you can catch the hover on the thumb so I have provided a solution with a hover on the whole slider